# Dealing with multiple parameters in Nginx rewrite

Tags: regex, http, url, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite that nginx calls like so:

```
        location ~* (css)$ {
rewrite ^(.*),(.*)$ /min/index.php?f=$1,/min/$2 last;
        }
```

And it's used on pages like this:

```
http://domain.com/min/framework.css,dropdown.css
```

Works all fine and dandy, but it's not scalable. Adding another element to the URL means I have to directly edit the nginx config. Ideally, I'd like to have nginx rewrite according to how many comma-delimited parameters are passed through the URL, rather than setting a fixed amount in the config. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand there is no solution using pure regular expressions. But you can make use of Perl capabilities, e.g.

```
http {
  perl_set $css_uri_arg 'sub {
    my $r = shift;
    my ($first,@rest) = split(/,/, $r->uri);
    join(',', ($first, map { "/min/$_"; } @rest));
  }';

  server {
    location ~* (css)$ {
      rewrite ^ /min/index.php?f=$css_uri_arg last;
    }
  }
}
```

Perl module is not built into Nginx by default, you should turn it on at build time. The documentation is [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxEmbeddedPerlModule).